# Validation not working on files created from a template

Tags: excel, vba

[image: ERROR IMAGE]I have a code which creates multiple files based on a template. The template file contains coded validations. But when the files are created, I tried to run the macros in which validations have been coded for but it throws up an error saying "application defined or object defined error".

Code to create multiple files using the template

```
Set wb = Workbooks.Add(strTemplate)

LastRowUV = sht1.Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
'MsgBox LastRowUV


Application.DisplayAlerts = False

For i = 2 To LastRowUV
    ThisFile = sht1.Range("F" & i).Value
    wb.SaveAs Filename:="\\lonfi0003.eur.xlPRithwik\Test\QB_" & ThisFile & ".xlsm", FileFormat:=52
Next i
```

Code for data validation

```
For i = 2 To LastRow1 + 1
        With sht.Range("A" & i).Validation
            .delete
            .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
            Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="=DropDown!A2:A" & LastRowAT
            .IgnoreBlank = True
            .InCellDropdown = True
            .InputTitle = ""
            .ErrorTitle = ""
            .InputMessage = ""
            .ErrorMessage = "Value not present in drop down."
            .ShowInput = True
            .ShowError = True
        End With
Next i
```

Comment: What is the value of `LastRowAT` when the error occurs? Can it be that it is 0?

Comment: No, its value is 9

Comment: And there is a sheet `Dropdown` in the same workbook as `sht`?

Comment: Yes there is a sheet dropdown